# OpenMutex/CreateMutex race condition

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

I'm trying to understand what is this race condition that OpenMutex MSDN article is warning me about. From MSDN:

> If your multithreaded application must repeatedly create, open, and
>   close a named mutex object, a race condition can occur. In this
>   situation, it is better to use CreateMutex instead of OpenMutex,
>   because CreateMutex opens a mutex if it exists and creates it if it
>   does not.

The same warning is contained in the book Windows Internals 6th edition part 1:

> Windows also supports Ex (Extended) versions of the
>   APIs—CreateEventEx, CreateMutexEx, CreateSemaphoreEx—that add another
>   argument for specifying the access mask. This makes it possible for
>   applications to properly use discretionary access control lists
>   (DACLs) to secure their objects without breaking their ability to use
>   the create object APIs to open a handle to them. You might be
>   wondering why a client application would not simply use OpenEvent,
>   which does support a desired access argument. Using the open object
>   APIs leads to an inherent race condition when dealing with a failure
>   in the open call—that is, when the client application has attempted to
>   open the event before it has been created. In most applications of
>   this kind, the open API is followed by a create API in the failure
>   case. Unfortunately, there is no guaranteed way to make this create
>   operation atomic—in other words, to occur only once. Indeed, it would
>   be possible for multiple threads and/or processes to have executed the
>   create API concurrently and all attempt to create the event at the
>   same time. This race condition and the extra complexity required to
>   try and handle it makes using the open object APIs an inappropriate
>   solution to the problem, which is why the Ex APIs should be used
>   instead.

Suppose that multiple threads are trying to call OpenMutex() simultaneously and the result will be failure. Then these threads will call CreateMutex(), so the first one will create the requested mutex, and others will open it. It's same situation if multiple threads are tryng to call CreateMutex() without preceding OpenMutex. But if CreateMutex() is not thread-safe and there will be a race condition, it also remains in situation without preceding OpenMutex().

Can someone clarify me what situation will lead to the race condition?

UPDATE 1:

> In most applications of this kind, the open API is followed by a
>   create API in the failure case. Unfortunately, there is no guaranteed
>   way to make this create operation atomic—in other words, to occur only
>   once. Indeed, it would be possible for multiple threads and/or
>   processes to have executed the create API concurrently and all attempt
>   to create the event at the same time.

Why this is a bad situation? After all threads will fail on OpenMutex() they will call CreateMutex() concurrently. Calling CreateMutex() one thread will create mutex and others will open it.

So i can't understand why using OpenMutex() with subsequent CreateMutex() is a bad idea?

UPDATE 2:

I wrote a test application that runs in multiple instances. Each instance in loop first tries to call OpenMutex(), then in case of an error it calls CreateMutex(). In both cases application writes results of open/creation of mutex, calls CloseHandle() and then goes to the next iteration. I've tried different number of instances with different timings (by adding sleep), but there is no any errors when calling CreateMutex() or any unexpected behavior.

So, the question remains open, why using OpenMutex() with subsequent CreateMutex() is a bad practice?

Comment: In the ideal case you would have one thread or process call CreateMutex and the other OpenMutex.  That requires an ordering guarantee, the one that calls OpenMutex must always run later.  Sometimes that guarantee is hard to come by, you might need a synchronization primitive (like a mutex) to get the right order and now you have another problem to solve.  Microsoft provided the easy solution by allowing both to call CreateMutex.  Whichever one runs later does not create it but just opens it.  The OS ensures it is atomic.

Comment: The same applies for any named kernel object - mutex, semaphore, file mapping, etc. "Creating" an object that already exists merely "opens" that object and returns a handle to it.

Comment: what you mean under `if CreateMutex() is not thread-safe` ? this api can be called safe in concurrent from multiple threads. will be created only single mutex(assume name the same). and every thread will be know - are it create or open mutex by call last error

Comment: Thanks for comments. But i can't understand why first call of OpenMutex() will lead to race condition, all threads will call then CreateMutex(). It's the same if there is no preceding OpenMutex().

Comment: race condition is call open object before object will be created. but all this create api have open_if semantic - it create object, if it not exist or open if exist. because this usual better just call create object api. except we sure that object already exist, or must not create it but only open

Comment: `OpenMutex` followed by `CreateMutex` is a classical [TOCTTOU race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use). The solution is to use an atomic operation instead. `CreateMutex` provides that.